# Why does my route makes a get request instead of a post request in a crud application?

Tags: node.js, express, crud

Why does my route makes a get request instead of a post request in a crud application? I have an html form that makes a post to `/api/zone'. But instead of the router executing the post function in my rest api, it makes a get call.

Here's my form:

```
    <form action="/api/zone" method="post">  <!--  The Crux of Rest API is really methods. It's a contract in REST API!-->
        <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' /><br />
        <input type='text' name='zipCodes' placeholder='Zip Code' /><br />
        <input type='submit' value='Create Zone' />
    </form>
```

My Api's:

```
router.get('/:resource', function(req, res, next) {

    var resource = req.params.resource

    if (resource == 'zone'){

        ZoneController.find(req.query, function(err, results){

            if (err) {
                res.json({
                    confirmation: 'fail',
                    message: err
                })

                return
            }

            res.json({
                confirmation: 'success1234',
                results: results
            })

        });
    }

})

router.post('/:resource', function(req, res, next){

    var resource = req.params.resource

    if (resource == 'zone') {

        ZoneController.create(req.body, function(err, result){
            if (err) {
                res.json({
                     confirmation: 'fail',
                     message: 'Not Created.'
                })
                return
            }

            res.json({
                confirmation: 'success',
                results: result
            })
        })
    }

})
```

I have the following versions of node and express:

> node - 6.11 
>  express - 4.15

Comment: I'm able to verify by putting in console logs with unique statement in each function. And, every time I submit the form, the statement found in the get function is shown in the terminal, rather than the one from post.

Comment: Where is the handler for `api/zone` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird issue, but I've seen this happen in Rails and I believe this is what is happening.

Basically, initially the correct request is sent to POST, and your correct `router.post` handler is invoked. Then however, that route handler cannot process the inputs in the form correctly, and for some reason sends a *redirect* to GET version of route (Note that your post and get routes match), instead of returning a, say, 400 error saying it can't process form.

Now as to reason why it can't process form, note that your route handler uses a slug on `/:resource`, meaning `req.params.resource` will return one string. And taking a look at your form, the `action` specified on there is `/api/zone`. So what's happening is the router interprets the *entire* string `/api/zone` as the slug, so when in the post handler you do `req.params.resource`, the returned value from that is `api/zone` and **not** `zone`, for which you have an if statement check.

So that's why it likely evaluates the `if`, fails, doesn't know what to do and sends a redirect to a GET.

You could therefore fix this by doing some parsing/validation on the POST route and/or adding an `else` to the if statement check to redirect somewhere or send an error.

Hope this helps!